# can i call ajax on using elements id and not on any event

Tags: jquery, ajax

suppose i have a

```
 if(ond1satisfied){
 <div id="checkA">
</div>}



   if(cond2satisfied){
 <div id="checkB">
</div>}
```

can i call ajax such as

```
      $.ajax({
       url: 'example.php',
      type: 'GET',

     success: function(data) {
//called when successful
$('#ajaxphp-results').html(data);
     },
       error: function(e) {
//called when there is an error
//console.log(e.message);
   }
       });
```

like

```
 $("#checkA").ajax({
       url: 'exampleA.php',
      type: 'GET',

     success: function(data) {
//called when successful
$('#ajaxphp-results').html(data);
     },
       error: function(e) {
//called when there is an error
//console.log(e.message);
   }
       });





   $("#checkB").ajax({
       url: 'exampleB.php',
      type: 'GET',

     success: function(data) {
//called when successful
$('#ajaxphp-results').html(data);
     },
       error: function(e) {
//called when there is an error
//console.log(e.message);
   }
       });
```

i.e., can i call ajax directly using id without any event

**there's a login form depending on the type of user (A,B)repective forms(A,B) will be displayed via ajax. here if the condition is satiafied the ajax to render formA  and ajax to render formB**

**can it be done**

is it possible ?
  if not how do i achieve so?

Comment: can you tell us the situation

Comment: Do you mean can you trigger the callback function manually?

Comment: @MjrKusanagi am a newbie to ajax i dint get you ....... what it meant trigger the callback function manually? i also have upadte my question

Comment: So, you want to display a particular form based on the Ajax response?

Comment: I down-voted the question because it's still unclear what you want to do. My understanding is this: 1.) You send ajax request, 2.) You render either form A or form B depending on the response from the server. So, what does the response from the server look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can call it on page load by wrapping your AJAX call inside `$(function(){...});` or `$(window).load(function() {...});`

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'example.php',
        type: 'GET',

        success: function (data) {
            //called when successful
            $('#ajaxphp-results').html(data);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            //called when there is an error
            //console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ya this thing i do know :)but my need is have updated my question please have a look